# how to calculate the gradients against some special layers's weights?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

TensorFlow use following method calculate the gradients(https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/eager/custom_training_walkthrough)

```
def grad(model, inputs, targets):
  with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    loss_value = loss(model, inputs, targets)
  return loss_value, tape.gradient(loss_value, model.trainable_variables)
```

the model use all variables in the model(model.trainable_variables) to calculate the gradients.If I want to calculate the gradients against some layers weights and bias without changing other weights, how to do it?